# Arrange functions based on their time complexity

Tags: algorithm, function, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

Rank the following functions representing running times from smallest to largest (in terms of
growth rate with respect to n) and group those functions that are in the same equivalence class

list of functions

```
2n^3+12n^2+5, 
8(log n)^2, 
1.5^n, 
n^4-12n^3, 
4n^3(log n), 
4n^3, 
n!, 
7n+6
```

```
My solution in ascending order is :
8(log n)^2 - logarithmic complexity
7n+6       - linear complexity
2n^3+12n^2+5, 4n^3(log n), 4n^3 - polynomial complexity
n^4-12n^3 - polynomial complexity
1.5^n - Factorial complexity
n! - Exponential complexity
```

Unsure if what I have done is correct. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say that `4n^3(log n)` is equivalent to `4n^3`?  Did you try to prove it?

Comment: I was not totally sure. I thought 4n^3(log n) might have a higher complexity. No, I did not try to prove.

Comment: Well then, I think you should try.  This is a mathematics question and every answer should be possible to prove mathematically.  If you can't justify your reasoning then you're not done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexities are as follows:

- 2<sup>3</sup>+12n<sup>2</sup>+5 = O(<sup>3</sup>)
- 8(log)<sup>2</sup> = O(log<sup>2</sup>)
- 1.5 = O(1.5)
- <sup>4</sup>−12<sup>3</sup> = O(<sup>4</sup>)
- 4<sup>3</sup>log = O(<sup>3</sup>log)
- 4<sup>3</sup> = O(<sup>3</sup>)
- ! = O(!)
- 7+6 = O()

When grouped by their complexities and put in ascending order:

- O(log<sup>2</sup>)

  - 8(log)<sup>2</sup>
- O()

  - 7+6
- O(<sup>3</sup>)

  - 2<sup>3</sup>+12n<sup>2</sup>+5
  - 4<sup>3</sup>
- O(<sup>3</sup>log)

  - 4<sup>3</sup>log
- O(<sup>4</sup>)

  - <sup>4</sup>−12<sup>3</sup>
- O(1.5)

  - 1.5
- O(!)

  - !

So there is essentially one difference with your output: O(<sup>3</sup>log) is not O(<sup>3</sup>): the first is of a greater order:

We can prove this by contradiction. If for a moment we assume that O(<sup>3</sup>log) is O(<sup>3</sup>), then we can find a <sub>0</sub> and a  such that <sup>3</sup>log ≤ <sup>3</sup> for all  > <sub>0</sub>. But this would mean that log ≤  or  ≤ 2. This is not true for any  > 2, and so the proposition does not hold.

Another correction: the labels "Exponential" and "Factorial" were inverted in your output.

O(!) is factorial and O(1.5) is exponential.